# InnoSetup - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE how to add the value?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, environment-variables, inno-setup, regedit

I have this in my innosetup script, but its not adding anything at all in the registry.

```
[Registry]    
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Test"; ValueData: "{app}\test.vbs";
```

Any idea why its not adding it?

EDIT:

**test.vbs:**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c runpython.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

**runpython.bat:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\dev_appserver.py" --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

Comment: Perhaps you have 64bit Windows. If yes, the the entry is added to `Wow6432Node`.

Comment: Aren't you looking with 64-bit regedit into 64-bit registry view node ? If you have 64-bit regedit, you'll find 32-bit view under `WoW` node.

Comment: How strange. Its indeed inserted in Wow6432Node. I do not understand this why its adding there?

Comment: Its a 64-bit Windows. After rebooting my test.exe was not launched.

Comment: You ran 64-bit regedit which has a 64-bit view to keys. 32-bit keys you can find under the `WoW` node. There is also 32-bit regedit which shows this view vice-versa. That's just how regedit represents view to registry. It is the view by [`registry redirector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: +1 - OK - Thank you. i used `HKLM64` instead of `HKLM` and used Check: IsWin64 on that line, now its showing correctly.

Comment: @TLama: Please see my edit. Registry entry is done but the test.vbs is not executing after rebooting the PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK -  solved, it was 32-bit/64-bit like mentioned in the comments.

InnoSetup issue:

```
[Registry]    
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Test"; ValueData: "{app}\test.vbs"; Check: IsWin64;
```

- On Windows 64-bit PC, here HKLM64 was required instead of HKLM

test.vbs issue:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c runpython.bat"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

- here the VBS did not executed because of
  `strArgs = "cmd /c ""C:\program files\blabla.bat"""`